# Can't pass static variable to the next scene (even with DDOL)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Maybe this is an extremly noob question but I've stuck on it for a week now.
I have a `PlayerInventory` and `AmmoContainer` classes that store collectables, keys, initialized (picked up) weapons and ammo. This classess are added to an empty GameObject in a scene that I'm passing to DontDestroyOnLoad.
The problem is I can't pass `weapons` variable to the next scene and I don't know why. Other variables like keys and collectables do transfer, though I couldn't check ammo yet.
I tried removing `static` from `weapons` and adjusting all the functions that use it but didn't work.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Linq;

public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int AmmoCount { get; private set; }
    public int StuffCollected { get; private set; }


    //---------OBJECTS--------------
    private List<Key> keys = new List<Key>(); 


    public UnityEvent<PlayerInventory> OnStuffCollected;

    public static Transform[] weapons = new Transform[9];

    private void Start()
    {
        //SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(gameObject, SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
        InventoryUI inventoryUI = GameObject.Find("StuffCollectedCountText").GetComponent<InventoryUI>();
        OnStuffCollected.AddListener(inventoryUI.UpdateStuffCollectedText);
        weapons[0] = GameObject.Find("Knife").transform;
    }




    public void StuffCollectedCount()
    {
        StuffCollected++;
        OnStuffCollected.Invoke(this);
    }
    public void AddKey(Key key)
    {
        keys.Add(key);
    }
    public bool HasKey(string keyId)
    {
        return keys.Any(key => key.keyId == keyId);
    }
}
public class AmmoContainer
{
    public Dictionary<AmmoType, int> maxAmmoTypeValues = new Dictionary<AmmoType, int>();
    public Dictionary<AmmoType, int> ammoTypeValues = new Dictionary<AmmoType, int>();

    public AmmoContainer()
    {
        maxAmmoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Melee, 0);
        maxAmmoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Pistol, 120);
        maxAmmoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Rifle, 240);
        maxAmmoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Shells, 50);
        maxAmmoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Energy, 400);

        ammoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Melee, 0);
        ammoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Pistol, 24);
        ammoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Rifle, 60);
        ammoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Shells, 6);
        ammoTypeValues.Add(AmmoType.Energy, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the game-objects in your weapons are not DDOL as well**, the problem is that your `weapons` contains component-reference belonging to a game-object. These game-object gets destroyed when loading any scene, which causes your `weapons` to lose its references as well *(hence, probably the null error your getting)*

---

Simplest way is to just DDOL any weapons when added:

```
public void UnequipWeapon(int slotNumber){
    if (weapons[slotNumber] == null) { return; }

    // Destroy the weapon when the player unequips it,
    // otherwise, the weapon will consistently persist due to DDOL
    Destroy(weapons[slotNumber].gameObject);
    weapons[slotNumber] = null;
}

public void AddWeapon(GameObject newWeapon, int slotNumber) {
    UnequipWeapon(slotNumber);

    DontDestroyOnLoad(newWeapon);
    weapons[slotNumber] = newWeapon.transform;
}
```

If `DDOL` on weapons is not possible, you could try storing references to the weapon's prefabs
Then, instantiating them on scene load and re-add them to the weapon's array.

Comment: But what about a knife weapon? It adds to the inventory on start and it doesn’t disappear in the next scene, getting no error either. Just all the weapons get taken away except for the knife.

Comment: @AlexBratov You can either check if the knife exists first, then create if it doesnt; Or you can just remove all weapons *(including the knife)* on scene load, to let the new scene load the knife again.

Comment: No, I mean knife already exists and still works after a transition to the next scene. Your hint about weapons variable not working due to lack of object references is valid and I’m still checking it out, but if so, isn’t the knife supposed to be erroring out? Because it doesn’t for some reason.

Comment: @AlexBratov I gave the answers on the assumption that DDOL was not set on all of the weapons, including knifes; So it might be that the knife is set as DDOL, or the knife was never used after loading a new scene *(no attempts was made to use the knife)*. Additionally, make sure that you do not have duplicated instances of `PlayerInventory` whenever you load a new scene. Maybe you can edit your question to provide more context, such as the implementation of how you set DDOL, how the `weapons` is being accessed, and your inspector/scene setup, implementation of the scene transition, etc.